# How to use UNNEST in JOIN structure?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I'm facing issues while using UNNEST function to work with arrays in JOIN structure in Google BigQuery.

I had the query to count MAU (monthly active users) for my mobile app, based on Firebase data in Google BigQuery. And it worked pretty good.

Then I tried to count users that completed particular event and it also worked.

However, when I try to filter the event by its parameters (that are saved in array), I faced issue using UNNEST function in JOIN structure.

The parameters:

```
event_params.key = 'isCommented'
```

and

```
event_params.value.string_value = 'true'
```

Without UNNEST function I encountered the following error:

```
Cannot access field key on a value with type 
ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, ...>>> at [32:20]
```

```
WITH
  calendar AS (
  SELECT
    day
  FROM
    UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY( (
        SELECT
          MIN(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
              event_date))
        FROM
          `***`.`***`.`***`), (
        SELECT
          MAX(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
              event_date))
        FROM
          `***`.`***`.`***`), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ) AS day )
SELECT
  c.day AS date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT m.user_pseudo_id ) AS MAU
  --  UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params1
FROM
  calendar AS c
JOIN
  `***`.`***`.`***` AS m
ON
  parse_DATE('%Y%m%d',
    m.event_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(c.day, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND c.day
WHERE
  event_name = 'eventCreation'
  AND event_params.key = 'isCommented'
  AND event_params.value.string_value = 'true'
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date
```

How can I use  UNNEST in case of using it in JOIN structure?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do array filtering isn't using `UNNEST`. please use `EXISTS` & `UNNEST` together.

For Example

```
WHERE
  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'isCommented' AND value.string_value = 'true')
```

The advantage to do array-subquery filtering is that it doesn't destroy the granularity which make query much more readable.